# I was wonder if we can clear "byte currently in cache" in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, memory-management

I used db.serverStatus().wiredTiger.cache
It showed information like
"bytes currently in the cache" : 6002288998

I was wonder if we can clear "bytes currently in the cache" since it generally grew up.

Comment: Why do you want to stop [WiredTiger caching data](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/wiredtiger/)?

Comment: I wonder "bytes currently in the cache" growing? It kept data that no longer usable in the project. Therefore, I want to clear previous data caching.